# npm run serve unexpected token ...options

Tags: npm, blockchain, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain

I am trying to run IBM blockchain election system, Evote. link=https://github.com/IBM/evote.
when I am trying to run client by using "npm run serve". I am getting following error.

```
ahmed@ahmed-Inspiron-3580:~/evote/web-app/client$ npm run serve

> client@0.1.0 serve /home/ahmed/evote/web-app/client
> vue-cli-service serve

/home/ahmed/evote/web-app/client/node_modules/open/index.js:29
        ...options
        ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:533:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ahmed/evote/web-app/client/node_modules/@vue/cli-shared-utils/lib/openBrowser.js:9:14)
```

[image: error]

Comment: Code in the affected module would be essential to anyone helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using a very old version of node.js. You can check the version by doing

```
node -v
```

you need to be using node 8 (it may not work with any version higher than that).

I would recommend using `nvm` as a mechanism for managing node versions. See https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm